# MultiBinding in WPF doesn't allow more than two bindings

Tags: c#

```
<MultiBinding  Converter="{StaticResource MergeValuesConverter}">
      <Binding Path="StructureID" />
      <Binding Path="SectionID" />
      <Binding Path="ParentStructureID" />                                    
</MultiBinding>
```

I am only getting the first two bindings.
Is there a way to get the third binding (ParentStructureID)?

Comment: Do a spell-check and format the question the next time you post one. Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: What are you binding element are you binding to?  Also you may want to post the code for your converter...

Comment: it does but you need to handle it in your `IMultiValueConverter` where you get `object[] values`

Comment: What is your code for `MergeValuesConverter`?  That's where the problem will be...